# How to combine a variable with a underscore and other word?

Tags: php, variables, concatenation

I need to combine a $variable with a underscore and word like this:

$agent = agent id
word is "declined."

```
$newvar = $agent_declined;
```

How can i do that?

Comment: See [PHP's variable variables](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: There seems to be a disagreement of what you are looking for exactly. Could you provide example and expected result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this: `$newvar = $agent . "_declined";`

In PHP, you combine strings by using `.`

Answer (score 3):

Use the concatenation:

```
<?php

$newvar = $agent . "_declined";

?>
```

Read [here!](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
$agent_declined = "foobar";
$id = "declined";
$varname = "\$agent_" . $id
$newvar = $$varname; // should give foobar
```

I would advise against the use of double `$$`, it's confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
${$variableName.'_declined'} = 'foo';
```

For more info, see [PHP: Variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php%20%22PHP:%20Variable%20variables)